# MySQL commit and rollback failed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, commit, rollback

I have a problem.

```
try {                   
    jdbcConnect( ); //get mysql connect
    conn.setAutoCommit( false );

    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement ( 
                    "INSERT INTO member ( member_name, member_introduce ) VALUES ( ?, ? )", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS );

    pstmt.setString( 1, "something" );
    pstmt.setString( 2, "something" );
    pstmt.executeUpdate( );
    rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys( );
    rs.next( );
    String no = Integer.toString( rs.getInt( 1 );

    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement ( "UPDATE account SET account_name = ? WHERE account_no = ?" );
    pstmt.setString( 1, "something");
    pstmt.setString( 2, no );
    pstmt.executeUpdate( );

    conn.commit( );         
    conn.setAutoCommit( true );

} catch ( SQLException t ) {            
    try {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.rollback();
            conn.setAutoCommit( true );
        }
    } catch ( SQLException e ) {
    }
}//close conn and prepareStatement
```

I was expect working commit.

But If an error occurs update statement, insert statement is running.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you are using MyISAM table instead of InnoDB. MyISAM does not support transaction at all.

Comment: spot on. This was my issue.